# How to measure bandwith of an SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm running a SSH Tunnel with OpenSSH on linux using the `subprocess` python module.
I want to find out how many bytes were sent and received from that SSH tunnel.

How can I find it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh(1)` provides no mechanism for this. The OS does not provide a mechanism for this. Packet sniffing with e.g. `tcpdump(1)` is an option, but that would probably require root privileges, and would only be approximate if `ssh(1)` connections are made to the remote peer *outside* of your application. [IPTables Accounting](http://wiki.openvz.org/Traffic_accounting_with_iptables) would give you similar tradeoffs, but would probably be much less overhead than `tcpdump(1)`.

*If* you don't mind being very approximate, you could keep track of all the data you send to and read from your subprocess. `ssh(1)` will compress data before encrypting it, so you might over-estimate the amount of data sent, but `ssh(1)` will also have some overhead for re-keying, channel control, message authenticity, and so on, so it might even come close for 'average' data.

Of course, if a router along the way decides to drop every other packet, your TCP stack will send twice the data, maybe more.

Very approximate indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could measure the raw ssh transfer with something like pv:

ssh user@remote -t "cat /dev/urandom" | pv > /dev/null
ssh user@remote -t "pv > /dev/null" < /dev/urandom

(you could try with /dev/zero - but if you are using ssh compression, you'd get a very unreal transfer rate.)